# Xcode Storyboard Reset to Suggested Constraints Error

Tags: xcode, ios-autolayout

Started getting this today after upgrading to iOS 11:

[image: Failed to automatically update constraints]

Any body have an ideas? I get this when I do Reset To Suggested Constraints:

[image: Reset to Suggested Constraints]

Was working for months until today. Here's the log:

```
=================================
```

## XCODE VERSION INFO:

Version = 9.0 (9A235)
Plugin Version = 13196
Beta Version = 0
OS Version = 10.12.6 (16G29)

=================================

## ARBITER ERROR:

Failed to run arbitration with options: {
    KeepRedundantDocumentConstraints = 1;
    OnlyArbitrateConstraintsForViews = "{(\n    >,\n    ; layer = >,\n    >,\n    ; layer = >,\n    ; layer = >,\n    ; layer = >\n)}";
    RelationshipHints =     {
        CommandKeyDown = 0;
        Source = 4;
    };
} (Failure reason: Left-over temporary explicit constraint:  UIView[0x7fb68bf370a0].Width = + 375.000000 containingView={} scoreVector=, roundingAdjustment=0)

=================================

## IDE ARBITRATION UNIT:

Register View Controller
     Top Layout Guide
     Bottom Layout Guide
     View frame={{0, 0}, {375, 667}} tAMIC=YES
        Email Address frame={{87, 272}, {200, 30}} tAMIC=YES
        ********* frame={{87, 321}, {200, 30}} tAMIC=YES
       Register frame={{87, 370}, {200, 40}} tAMIC=YES
       First Name frame={{87, 170}, {200, 30}} tAMIC=YES
       Last Name frame={{87, 219}, {200, 30}} tAMIC=YES

=================================

## BACKTRACE:

0   -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager _scheduleArbitrationOfUnit:withOptions:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  1   -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager _runAutolayoutCommandForArbitrationUnits:withBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  2   -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager _whitelistAndDecideConstraintsForItems:withOptions:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  3   -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager clearAndAddSuggestedConstraintsForItems:inAllConfigurations:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  4   **65-[IBDocument clearAndAddSuggestedConstraintsForItems:fromSource:]_block_invoke.4171 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  5   -[IBMemberRelationshipHelper handleOperation:onObjects:inDocument:hints:currentConfigurationOnlyHandler:defaultConfigurationHandler:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6   -[IBMemberRelationshipHelper handleOperation:onObjects:inDocument:fromSource:currentConfigurationOnlyHandler:defaultConfigurationHandler:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  7   -[IBDocument clearAndAddSuggestedConstraintsForItems:fromSource:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  8   -[IBAbstractDocumentEditor clearAndAddSuggestedConstraintsInArbitrationUnit:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  9   _os_activity_initiate_impl (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
 10   -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 11   __37-[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:]_block_invoke (in DVTKit)
 12   DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 13   -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 14   -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] (in AppKit)
 15   -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] (in AppKit)
 16   _os_activity_initiate_impl (in libsystem_trace.dylib)
 17   -[NSMenu performActionForItemAtIndex:] (in AppKit)
 18   -[NSMenu _internalPerformActionForItemAtIndex:] (in AppKit)
 19   -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonCommandProcessEvent:handlerCallRef:] (in AppKit)
 20   NSSLMMenuEventHandler (in AppKit)
 21   DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) (in HIToolbox)
 22   SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) (in HIToolbox)
 23   SendEventToEventTarget (in HIToolbox)
 24   SendHICommandEvent(unsigned int, HICommand const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned char, void const*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, OpaqueEventRef**) (in HIToolbox)
 25   SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers (in HIToolbox)
 26   SendMenuItemSelectedEvent (in HIToolbox)
 27   FinishMenuSelection(SelectionData*, MenuResult*, MenuResult*) (in HIToolbox)
 28   PopUpMenuSelectCore(MenuData*, Point, double, Point, unsigned short, unsigned int, Rect const*, unsigned short, unsigned int, Rect const*, Rect const*, __CFDictionary const*, __CFString const*, OpaqueMenuRef**, unsigned short*) (in HIToolbox)
 29   _HandlePopUpMenuSelection8(OpaqueMenuRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, unsigned int, Point, unsigned short, unsigned int, Rect const*, unsigned short, Rect const*, Rect const*, __CFDictionary const*, __CFString const*, OpaqueMenuRef**, unsigned short*) (in HIToolbox)
 30   _HandlePopUpMenuSelectionWithDictionary (in HIToolbox)
 31   _NSSLMPopUpCarbonMenu3 (in AppKit)
 32   -[NSCarbonMenuImpl popUpMenu:atLocation:width:forView:withSelectedItem:withFont:withFlags:withOptions:] (in AppKit)
 33   -[NSSegmentedCell _trackSelectedItemMenu] (in AppKit)
 34   -[NSSegmentedCell _displayDelayedMenu] (in AppKit)
 35   __NSFireTimer (in Foundation)
 36   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** (in CoreFoundation)
 37   __CFRunLoopDoTimer (in CoreFoundation)
 38   __CFRunLoopDoTimers (in CoreFoundation)
 39   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 40   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 41   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 42   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 43   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 44   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 45   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 46   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 47   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) trackEventsMatchingMask:timeout:mode:handler:] (in AppKit)
 48   -[NSDragEventTracker trackEvent:usingHandler:] (in AppKit)
 49   -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
 50   -[NSSegmentedCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in AppKit)
 51   -[NSControl mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
 52   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
 53   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] (in AppKit)
 54   -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 55   -[IDEWorkspaceWindow sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 56   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 57   -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 58   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 59   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 60   start (in libdyld.dylib)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question; it's an Xcode bug report that should go to Apple, not to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you fixed it somehow?

Comment: I've got same error here.

Comment: I have also confused ... How to add constraints in xcode 9